# Join in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, join, laravel-5.1, fetch

I'm new to Laravel and I'm still working on my Project using this Framework. In my project, I use an SQL JOIN but I don't know how to retrieve/fetch data on the joined table. 
Can anybody help me on this one?
I really appreciate your help. Thanks!
Here is a simple example!

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
        ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
        ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
        ->get();
```

Comment: `$users` is an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` which is an `Iterable` and `Countable` store. This stores objects of type `stdClass` (in this case), each containing the fields you selected in your query.

Comment: So how can I fetch the data? Can you help me with that?

Comment: You have already fetched the data in your example above.

Comment: Ok thanks. I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = \DB::table('users')
          ->join('contacts', 'contacts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
          ->join('orders', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
          ->select('users.id as id', 'contacts.phone as phone',  'orders.price as price')
          //Where condition here if exist
          ->get();
```

$users will now have the array of values.Loop it in an array if necessary.
Eg:

```
forearch($users as $user)
    { $user->id;
      $user->phone;
    }
```

Like that.